# JButton not invoking actionPerformed on any subsequent click in same GUI instance

Tags: java, swing

I have a JButton that will not allow me to perform the same action on any subsequent click on it after the first in the same Swing GUI instance.

```
    JButton Run = new JButton("Run");
    Run.setLocation(290, 70);
    Run.setSize(120, 30);
    buttonPanel.add(Run);
    Run.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (Run.isEnabled()) {
                errorLabel.setText("");
                    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(Run.class);
                        errorMessageDisplay(result);

            }
        }
    });

totalGUI.setOpaque(true);
    return totalGUI;
```

}

So far I thought about and tried removing the JPanel and painting all of the buttons back on, and disabling/renabling buttons.

The errorMessageDisplay method is as follows:

```
public void errorMessageDisplay(Result resultPass) {
    if (resultPass.getFailureCount() > 0) {
        errorLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
        errorLabel.setVisible(true);
        errorLabel.setText(" Failed");
    }

    else {
        errorLabel.setForeground(Color.green);
        errorLabel.setText(" Passed");
        errorLabel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, the `JUnitCore.runClasses(Run.class);` call is suspicous. Also, it would be good to know what does the `errorMessageDisplay()` do. I believe, the problem is with one of these methods.

You can verify this with the following experimental code. Just be careful not to push it into production.

```
JButton run = new JButton("Run");
run.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (Run.isEnabled()) {
                errorLabel.setText("");
                System.out.println("Run action peformed.");

            }
        }
```

**Update** Since the `errorMessageDisplay()` looks okay, it's probably a Threading problem with `JUniCore`. Thus I'd try the following code:

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); // this runs stuff in background
JButton run = new JButton("Run");
// ..
run.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (Run.isEnabled()) {
                executor.execute(new Runnable() { // This is how we run stuff in background. You can use lambdas instead of Runnables.
                    public void run() {
                        final Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(Run.class); // Run.class is different from the current JButton run.
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { // Now we go back to the GUI thread
                            public void run() {
                                errorMessageDisplay(result);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try to implement this now. May I ask what the argument '5' is for?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to do it. I have added another example of the last piece of code in that block. Maybe it has somehting to do with it?

Comment: I also tried the first piece of advice regarding the "run action performed" messages which worked, so I guess it is to do with threading as you suggested?

Comment: Strangely, I put some sysout checks in, throughout the code sample you gave and they all display perfectly fine in the console, but do not execute the script

Comment: @lxuboiro the `5` argument is for specifying 5 threads. In this case `1` would be fine too. If you have a shared executor service in a larger gui, then it can be useful to have more than 1 background thread.

Comment: @lxuboiro I guess the problem with the test script is that `Run.class` refers to `JButton.class` because you define `Run` this way: `JButton Run = new JButton(...)`; I would try this instead: `JButton run = new JButton(...)`;

Comment: How do you define your tests in `Run.java` ?

Comment: I have identified the issue, which is this line: 'private static WebDriver driver = CreateWebDriver.getDriver("chrome");' after I moved 'WebDriver driver = CreateWebDriver.getDriver("chrome")' to inside the test and it worked fine when I tested. The issue is I have methods which utilise driver and now cannot reach it, unless I define it as a global variable. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think this deserves another question. So we'll be able to see the code example more clearly. Can you link the question url here, when you asked it?

Comment: I have posted a new question on the issue @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874932/cannot-store-webdriver-as-global-variable-and-execute-a-test-more-than-once-in-t